# Win-Place-Show in Horse Racing

Tags: terminology, betting, horse-racing

Horse racing (such as the Kentucky Derby) results usually contains the terms Win, Place, and Show, with the horse associated with each term.

What is win, place, and show, and what significance does each term have for the horse associated with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Win is a horse that finishes in **first** place in the race.
- Place is a horse that finishes in **second** place in the race.
- Show is a horse that finishes in **third** place in the race.

On betting...

- A **win** bet is the act of placing a bet on one horse that the better thinks will finish first in the race.
- A **place** bet is the act of placing a bet on one horse that the better thinks will finish first OR second place in the race. If the this occurs, the better wins. The payout is the same whether the horse that was betted on places first or second.
- A **show** bet is the act of placing a bet on one horse that the better thinks will finish first, second OR, third place in the race. If the this occurs, the better wins. The payout is the same whether the horse that was betted on places first, second or third.
- A **win-show** bet is the act of placing a bet on one horse that the better thinks will finish first OR second place in the race. If the this occurs, the better wins. But unlike the place bet, the position that the horse finishes in the race determines the payout.
- A **win-show-place** bet is the act of placing a bet on one horse that the better thinks will finish first, second OR third place in the race. If the this occurs, the better wins. But unlike the show bet, the position that the horse finishes in the race determines the payout.

[Source](http://www.thesportsgeek.com/sports-betting/horse-racing/win-place-show/)